# executing a command on system() in C - linux

Tags: c, linux, datetime, posix

I run the code below,

```
int main() {
  char settime_parameters[13]= "042122142013";
  char command[25];
  sprintf(command, "date %s", settime_parameters );
  printf("%s\n",command);
  system("commad");
}
```

and I get this output:

```
date 042122142013
sh: 1: commad: not found
```

however, if I run `date 042122142013` on the terminal, it works fine and changes the system time. I wonder why it does not work when I execute it through the `system()`?

Thank you.

Comment: system(command); without any " and using the correct variable name command ( and not commad ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need this:

```
system(command);
```

without the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
system("commad");
```

should be

```
system(command);
```

without quotes